# Re-associate AWS Elastic IP with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I use Ansible for spinning up EC2 instances and deploying services to them. I would like to re-associate an elastic IP which is already associated with an existing EC2 instance to a new instance with as little down time as possible. Do I get it right that this only works in two steps with the Ansible [`ec2_eip`](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_eip_module.html) module?

- Disassociate from old instance (state absent)
- Associate to new one (state present)

There is no way to do it in one step as with the `allow-reassociation` option of the [`ec2-associate-address`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AssociateAddress.html) CLI command, right?

Comment: You can execute any shell command directly with the shell module of Ansible.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/2205) which might help you.

This PR is adding 2 modules : `boto3` and `boto3_wait`. It allows you to call any [Boto 3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/) client operation.

You could use it like so :

```yaml
- name: Re-associate Elastic IP
  boto3:
    name: ec2
    region: us-east-1
    operation: associate_address
    parameters:
      AllowReassociation: yes
      InstanceId: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      AllocationId: eipalloc-xxxxxxxx
```

If you're interrested by this feature, feel free to vote up on the PR. :)